# csrfguard default implementation to protect from CSRF attacks. But getting issue: error:required token is missing from the request

Tags: csrf, guard

We are using csrfguard default implementation to protect our project from CSRF attacks. But getting issue: error:required token is missing from the request on every page except login.
I am assuming the reason is that we invalidate our session and create new one on after login. Any suggestions?